# How to persist data using a postgres database, Docker, and Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, docker, persistence, kubernetes

I am trying to mount a persistent disk on my container which runs a Postgres custom image. I am using Kubernetes and following [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/) tutorial.

This is my `db_pod.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lp-db
  labels:
    name: lp-db
spec:
  containers:
    - image: my_username/my-db
      name: my-db
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: my-db
      volumeMounts:
        - name: pg-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumes:
    - name: pg-data
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: my-db-disk
        fsType: ext4
```

I create the disk using the command `gcloud compute disks create --size 200GB my-db-disk`.

However, when I run the pod, delete it, and then run it again (like in the tutorial) my data is not persisted.

I tried multiple versions of this file, including with PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims, I tried changing the mountPath, but to no success.

### Edit

Dockerfile for creating the Postgres image:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Get Postgres
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Install virtualenv (will be needed later)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        postgresql-9.4 \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        python-virtualenv \
        strace \
        supervisor


# Grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ca-certificates wget

# make the "en_US.UTF-8" locale so postgres will be utf-8 enabled by default
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
RUN echo "log_directory='/var/log/postgresql'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

# Add all code from the project and all config files
WORKDIR /home/projects/my-project
COPY . .

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

# Expose an entrypoint and a port
RUN chmod +x scripts/sh/*
EXPOSE 5432
ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/sh/entrypoint-postgres.sh"]
```

And entrypoint script:

```
echo " I am " && gosu postgres whoami

gosu postgres /etc/init.d/postgresql start && echo 'Started postgres'
gosu postgres psql --command "CREATE USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'mypassword';"  && echo 'Created user'
gosu postgres createdb -O myuser mydb && echo 'Created db'

# This just keeps the container alive.
tail -F /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong off the bat. Can you elaborate on how you confirmed that the data is not persisted? (did you log into the database and select *, or via the wordpress frontend). Can you also look for suspicious messages running kubectl describe pod on the mysql and wordpress pods?

Comment: I simply added data from the fronted, then deleted both pods, and then restarted them. I tend to believe that the problem lies within the fact that my database is being created when I build the image and the external volume is no longer able to be mounted onto existing data...

Comment: Posting your dockerfile would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end, it seems that the real problem was the fact that I was trying to create the database from my entrypoint script. 
Things such as creating a db or a user should be done *at container creation time* so I ended up using the standard Postgres image, which actually provides a simple and easy way to create an user and a db.

This is the fully functional configuration file for Postgres.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    name: postgres
spec:
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres
      env:
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: myuser
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: mydb
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: pg-data
  volumes:
    - name: pg-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pg-data-claim
```

Thanks to all those who helped me :)

Comment: In my case problem was with mountPath - it was /var/lib/postgresql But when I changed it to /var/lib/postgresql/data - now it works

Comment: @PavelAgarkov, would you like me to add this to the answer or do you want to make it a separate answer in itself? I think either of these should be done to quickly help people with the same problem.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I did not pay enough attention at the first place. And id does not matter whether you use PV/PVC or directly access gcePersistentDisk. Sorry for bothering:)

Comment: @PavelAgarkov I ran into the same issue with the same fix and managed to locate the source down to this line in the Postgres Dockerfile github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/… where a VOLUME is explicitly declared at this location - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140161/kubernetes-timescaledb-statefulset-changes-lost-on-pod-recreation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

- does your custom postgresql persist data at /var/lib/postgresql/data?
- are you able to get logs from your postgresql container and spot anything interesting?
- when your pod is running, can you see the mountpoints inside your container and check the persistent disk is there?

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't, that's the problem. 2. No, the only log I get has four lines that say nothing meaningful :( 3. The persistent disk is being mounted, but it  only contains a `lost+found` directory and nothing else. I tried manually creating a file inside it, and it still doesn't persist...

Answer (score 0):

I followed this scenario and I was able to persist my data by changing the mountPath to  /var/lib/postgresql and also reproduced using cassandra (i.e. /var/lib/cassandra for mountPath)

I was able to delete/restart pods from different nodes/hosts and still see my "users" table and the data I previously entered.  However, I was not using a custom image, I just used standard docker images.

Comment: It also works for me using the standard docker postgres image :) I think I will start from there.