# kubernetes timescaledb statefulset: Changes lost on pod recreation

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-aks, persistent-volumes, timescaledb

I have a Timescaledb server running as StatefulSet in AKS. It appears when I delete and recreate timescaledb pod, the changes are lost even though the pod is associated to the initially associated PV (persistent volume). Any help is appreciated.

Below is the PV, PVC config of statefulset extracted by running `kubectl get statefulset timescaledb -o yaml`

```
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: timescaledb
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -c
        - config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: timescaledb-secret
        image: docker.io/timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg9.6
        name: timescaledb-backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: server
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "3"
            memory: 6Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: timescaledbdata
        - mountPath: /etc/postgresql
          name: timescaledb-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: timescaledb-config
        name: timescaledb-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: standard
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: timescaledbdata
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      dataSource: null
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 200Gi
    status:
      phase: Pending
```

Below demonstrates a temp DB test_db created is lost after pod recreation and during the whole process, the pod was associated to the same PV/disk on Azure.

```
root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k get pvc -l app=timescaledb
NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
timescaledbdata-timescaledb-0   Bound    pvc-c7eb99cf-6a6b-11e9-b661-be660567cc75   200Gi      RWO            default        83d

root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k exec -ti timescaledb-0 bash
bash-4.4# psql -U postgres;
psql (9.6.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create database test_db;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test_db   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
(4 rows)


root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k get pods | grep timescale
timescaledb-0                         1/1     Running   0          12m
root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k delete pod/timescaledb-0                            
pod "timescaledb-0" deleted                                                                                                                                         
root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k get pods | grep timescale       
timescaledb-0                         1/1     Running   0          14s   

root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k exec -ti timescaledb-0 bash                                                                                                             
bash-4.4# psql -U postgres
psql (9.6.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges                                                                                    
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------                                                                                 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +                                                                                 
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres                                                                                  
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +                                                                                 
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres                                                                                  
(3 rows)

root@e70a91715239:~/keys# k get pvc -l app=timescaledb
NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
timescaledbdata-timescaledb-0   Bound    pvc-c7eb99cf-6a6b-11e9-b661-be660567cc75   200Gi      RWO            default        83d
```

Possibly it is reinitialising as hinted. Please see [logs](https://siaitesting.blob.core.windows.net/shared/timescaledb.log?sp=r&st=2019-07-22T16:46:31Z&se=2019-08-31T00:46:31Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=gdoyeem8a4CLD6Qk7yLYFsqaYUbJznUthrH1E6XMrmI%3D&sr=b). Any pointers on why it would do that.

Update 1:
I had a look at the mounts in the `timescale` pod, it seems to have different partitions for `/var/lib/postgresql` and `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. I do not understand why.

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /dev/termination-log
shm                      64.0M      4.0K     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /etc/hostname
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /etc/hosts
/dev/sdc                196.7G     59.3M    196.7G   0% /var/lib/postgresql
/dev/sda1                96.9G     22.1G     74.8G  23% /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Do not understand how the above mounts happen for below config

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: timescaledbdata
        - mountPath: /etc/postgresql
          name: timescaledb-config
```

Comment: Where do you mount the volume and where do you store the data for your DB?

Comment: hi Charles, I have now added most part of the statefulset configuration to the post.

Comment: well, the obvious question would be, does the data get dumped to disk? did you consult timescaledb docs to verify how to test that and how to make it grab the data from disk if it is there?

Comment: Judging by your output, the newly created pod has done an `initdb` on the directory it needs to use for PGDATA. Without having all the details, that looks like it is encountering an empty volume/directory on startup.

To troubleshoot this, you will have to have a look at the logs of the newly spun up pod and see what it does and why.

Comment: Hi Feike, thanks for the hint. It looks like it reinitialising with calling all those entrypoint files. Do you see a problem with how timescaledb pod is brought up? I cannot figure out why it would reinitialise.

Comment: I have added logs of timescaledb to the original post

Comment: is this a problem which postgresql.conf showing as a symlink which is a file coming from configmap key `bash-4.4# ls -l /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Jul 23 12:53 /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf -> ..data/postgresql.conf`. i need to see whether absence of postgresql.conf will result in reinitialisation.

Comment: The Docker image itself seems fine, the following sequence of events works fine for example:

Spin up a container with a host directory as a volume, e.g.:

1. docker run --rm -v $HOME/mypgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data docker.io/timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg9.6
2. Create a table
3. Stop the container (it will be removed)
4. Start another container with the same volume
5. Create table fails: relation already exists

So, I think you should be looking at your volumes, they seem to be empty when presented to a new pod. More of a kubernetes than postgres/timescale thing it seems.

Comment: Your observation is correct. I did not have a problem when I ran local with docker-compose. With docker-compose, I did not lose changes on `down` and `up`. I noticed the mounts on the timescaledb pod in k8s are different for `/var/lib/postgresql` and `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. Do you know why this could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was there was a VOLUME declaration for `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in `postgres:9.6` Dockerfile which caused additional mount on the container. That mount was ephemeral when we had the volume mount at `/var/lib/postgresql`. But we were not able to mount AKS volume to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` because the volume came with `lost+found` subdirectory and Postgres expects empty directory to store DB files.

The fix was to mount volume at `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and tell Postgres to use a subdirectory underneath `/var/lib/postgresql/data` to store files with `PGDATA` env var.

Below are the relevant parts of fix in the k8s statefulset configuration

```
env:
- name: PGDATA
  value: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/dbfiles"        
...
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  name: timescaledata
```